# Pass array as query parameter and fetch it with `getAll()` function (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, router

Could someone please say if it's possible to directly pass the array as query param and retrieve it with [`getAll()`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#getall) function.

```js
const queryParams = selectedItems.map(item => item.id);
this.router.navigate(['/item'], {
  relativeTo: this.route,
  queryParams: { item: queryParams }
});
```

I'm looking for an example but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Could you provide one or more use cases or examples that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in the recipient component to fetch the query parameters through `queryParamMap` which returns an `Observable<ParamMap>` that contains the `getAll()` function you were referring to.

Try the following

**item.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css'],
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const queryParam = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('item');
    console.log('`item` obtained through `get()`:', queryParam);
    const queryParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.getAll('item');
    console.log('`item` obtained through `getAll()`:', queryParams);
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-qohud4?file=src/app/item/item.component.ts)